# cpumask array defined with size 0

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I'm investigating the Linux kernel (specifically the load balance area).
in the kernel (sched.h) there is a declaration of a struct :

> struct sched_group

which looks like this:

```
struct sched_group {
    struct sched_group *next;   /* Must be a circular list */
    atomic_t ref;

    unsigned int group_weight;
    struct sched_group_power *sgp;

    /*
     * The CPUs this group covers.
     *
     * NOTE: this field is variable length. (Allocated dynamically
     * by attaching extra space to the end of the structure,
     * depending on how many CPUs the kernel has booted up with)
     */
    unsigned long cpumask[0];
};
```

what I don't understand is the use of a cpumask array with the size 0.
any explanation would be much appreciated :)

Comment: This is a GCC variant of what is usually called [the struct hack](http://c-faq.com/struct/structhack.html).  The C Standard does not cover this behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The size of cpumask should be variant based on different platforms that has different number of CPUs, that's why it cannot define a fixed length array. GNU C supports [a variable-length object](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html), it should be the last element of a structure.